# C# Run Tasks in parallel and associate each with input

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task, task-parallel-library

```cs
public class Input
{
    public bool ParameterOne { get; set; }
    public string ParameterTwo { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `List<Input>` that I want to process in parallel, keeping the input associated with the output. I loop through this list to build `Task`s.

```cs
var results = new List<(Input, Output)>();
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Output output = await Process(input);
    results.Add((input, output));
}
```

But this is not operating in parallel. I would like it to.

```cs
var inputsAndTasks = new List<(Input Input, Task<Output> OutputTask)>();
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Task<Output> output = Process(input);
    inputsAndTasks.Add((input, output));
}
Output[] results = await Task.WhenAll(inputsAndTasks.Select(i => i.OutputTask));
// results are no longer associated with their inputs!
```

How can I run this in parallel but retain the input association with the output? I don't want to make the input an object on the output.

Comment: `var results = inputs.AsParallel().Select(input => 
{
    Output output = await Process(input);
    return (input, output);
}).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an alternative approach that avoids using tasks altogether by taking advantage of "AsParallel"

```
IList<Input> inputs = new List<Input>();
// populate inputs here

IDictionary<Input, Output> associations = new Dictionary<Input, Output>();
associations.AddRange(inputs.AsParallel()
                        .Select(async i => 
                            { Output o = await Process(i); 
                              return new KeyValuePair<Input, Output>(i, o);
                            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just await the `WhenAll` then do a loop to match up the input and output

```
var inputsAndTasks = new List<(Input Input, Task<Output> OutputTask)>();
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Task<Output> output = Process(input);
    inputsAndTasks.Add((input, output));
}

await Task.WhenAll(inputsAndTasks.Select(i => i.OutputTask));

var results = new List<(Input, Output)>();
foreach (var x in inputsAndTasks)
{
    Output output = await x.OutputTask;
    results.Add((x.Input, output));
}
```

Since you already know all the individual output tasks are complete doing the `await` in that second loop will return the result immediately.